# When can a generic parameter never be null

Tags: c#, generics, null, resharper, language-specifications

In a generic `GetHashCode(T foo)` method, I check whether `foo` is `null`. 
However I just stumbled upon a strange Resharper warning.

In the following code, can `foo` never be `null`?

```
private class FooComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T: Foo
{
    public int GetHashCode(T foo)
    {
        // resharper warning:  "Expression is always false"
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null,foo)) return 0; 

        // ... calculate hash
    }
}
```

However as far as I can tell, the following is perfectly legal:

```
Foo foo = null;
var fooComparer = new FooComparer<Foo>();
int hash = fooComparer.GetHashCode(foo);
```

Comment: Yes your code is perfectly legal.

Comment: Is `Foo` a value or a reference type?

Comment: `Foo` is a class, not a struct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode` has contract `[NotNull]` for its parameter because it has implementations that throw an exception when `null` is provided as an argument.

If you want to use `FooComparer<T>.GetHashCode` directly and exception-safe for `null` as its argument, you can annotate it as follows:

```
public int GetHashCode([JetBrains.Annotations.CanBeNull] T foo)
{
    // resharper warning:  "Expression is always false"
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null,foo)) return 0; 

    // ... calculate hash
}
```

Nevertheless analysis for `[Not-Null]`-parameters must be improved. This bug exists for similar code in http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-304111

Answer (score 5):

[MSDN for `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132155.aspx)  says:

> **Exceptions:**
>
> `ArgumentNullException` The type of `obj` is a reference type and `obj` is `null`.

This seems to imply that calling `GetHashCode<T>(T obj)` with a `null` parameter violates the contract of `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

I assume Resharper assumes that callers adhere to that contract, and thus never pass in `null`.

Comment: Good point! There seems to be some inconsistency in the MDSN documentation, as for example [this implementation of IEqulityComparer.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) uses the same null check as I do.

Comment: I for one implement my `GetHashCode` just like you do (Expect that I avoid `ReferenceEquals`, because it causes boxing). Returning a constant seems like the cleanest choice for `GetHashCode`.