# ReSharper claims that my expression is always true? Is it correct or is it a bug?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, resharper-8.0

ReSharper is claiming that my null check against serviceProvider is always true, which is odd. I figured that serviceProvider very well might be null. Am I wrong here, or is this a ReSharper bug?

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    switch (Mode)
    {
        case BindingMode.TwoWay:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid binding mode.");

        case BindingMode.OneWayToSource:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid binding mode.");

        case BindingMode.OneWay:
        case BindingMode.OneTime:
            break;

        case BindingMode.Default:
            if (serviceProvider != null) // Expression is always true?? O.o
            {
                // Returns something possibly...
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid binding mode.");

        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected binding mode.");
    }

    return base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
}
```

Update:

I created a console application, and the following code gives a warning as well (from ReSharper) `Possible null assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute.`

```
var binding = new CustomBinding();
binding.ProvideValue(null);
```

Comment: sounds like a R# bug, unless you haven't shown the full code?

Comment: well, can you send it a null value and confirm it's wrong?

Comment: @Jonesy: ReSharper warns me if I attempt to pass in null as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.typeextension.providevalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> You can pass null for serviceProvider, but only if this TypeExtension
>   instance was established with an initial true type in the constructor
>   rather than a typeName. Otherwise, this markup extension
>   implementation relies on services based on the passed serviceProvider.
>   It must not be null. The serviceProvider is expected to provide a
>   service for IXamlTypeResolver.

Also you can view [When can a generic parameter never be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457971/when-can-a-generic-parameter-never-be-null) for more information about this.

Apparently, if i am correct, this method has a contract [NotNull] for its parameter because some implementations throw errors upon null arguments.

Answer (score -4):

Since ProvideValue is a function that needs IServiceProvider 
Resharper correctly assumes that if the serviceProvider is null is being checked prior to calling the ProvideValue function thus the espression is always true

Comment: Resharper makes no such assumptions, someone could call the method with `ProvideValue(null);`

Comment: I've seen it quite frequently in older versions so Ill stick to my answer in 9.0 though that particular code doesn't evaluate as always true. Kill me Bad judgement :)